# Angular2: How to move to Angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Today, I reinstalled angular-cli by typing:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then, I started a new Angular project by:

```
sudo ng new newproj
```

When I opened the package.json file of the new project, I saw that Angular project is, surprisingly, 2.3.1.

What do I have to do so I'll be able create Angular 4 project?

I followed this link: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

and I did:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
sudo npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm cache clean
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
sudo ng new new-proj
```

and still the new project was 2.3.1 version.

Comment: whats the version on ng-cli installed globally, you can check by running `ng -v`, if it is 1.0.0 then only it will create 4.0.0 ng project.

Comment: There are few more steps than that to consider; start here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

Comment: @R.Richards, I edited my post

Comment: @CrazySynthax; the link I provided has all the information you need to correct your situation.

Comment: @CrazySynthax This is odd. Are you using a npm registry other than the default? When you run `ng -v`, what version do you see? What npm and node versions are you running?

Answer (score 0):

you have to un-install the angular cli and re-install it again

```
sudo npm rm @angular/cli -g
sudo npm install @angular/cli -g
```

Use `sudo` if you are using macOS or Linux, and if you are using Windows surround `@angular/cli` with double quotations

Answer (score 0):

1) it's not a good practice to use

```
sudo ...
```

it would be much better to run everything from current user

2) don't you receive

```
You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.
```

after running

```
sudo ng new new-proj
```

?

3) try to run

```
sudo ng new new-proj
```

in another folder (outside of current project's one)